# ASP.Net - Populate dropdownlist from sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have an site with a dropdownlist where I need to use a sharepoint list as a datasource. 
The site is NOT a part of the sharepoint, but is running besides it. 
Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you look at any of SharePoint's data access methods, like the server and client-side APIs? There are quite a few articles in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: That is half the problem, I don't know what to look for. I just found the ClientContext class, which I'll look more into.